# Spring batch one reader multiple writers

Tags: spring, spring-batch

Is it possible in spring batch to have one reader read the data and that data being split to multiple writers for processing running parallel?

**Steps:**
Reader : JdbcCursorItemReader reads 100 records
10 Parallel Writers: Each ItemWriter gets 10 records to process.

I've looked at:

**CompositeItemWriter**: seems to passes all the read items to all the writers when I need to split the items evenly to the writers.

**BackToBackPatternClassifier**: I don't really need a classifier because I'm splitting items evenly.

Is there another way of just having one reader and multiple writers ?

Or I can just manually create threads in my Writer ?

Comment: You probably want to throw Spring Integration into the mix, the job of splitting and then handling to 10 different instances of writer can be done cleanly and easily. You can aggregate later if you wish to too!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do you mean by "multiple writers"?

What you are trying to achieve seems NOT multiple writers, but a single writer with multiple-threads.

To be clear, when we are talking about "multiple writer", we mean a reader read a chunk, and need to do different kind of "writing" for the chunk.  e.g. you may have a PlayerRecordReader which read Player from somewhere, and you have PlayerDbWriter and PlayerFileWriter which writes to DB and File.  Multiple writer are not for distributing the load.

For case that you want the writing to be done in parallel, what you need is a single writer (of course you need to make it thread-safe) and using executor in your step definition.  This page in Spring Batch give you clear instruction on how to do it.  http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html/scalability.html#multithreadedStep

Comment: Yep, that's what I meant multiple threads. Sorry!
The have here is Multi-threaded step (reader and writer) and is not specific to a writer. I want the reader to be called ones. I've chose to do this by calling the Writer logic in my Writer class in a Runnable (Thread) class. Thanks for the reply :)

Comment: What do you mean by that? You want one chunk to be read, and want the same chunk to be processed multiple times concurrently?  But why? I strongly suggest you revisit what you are doing.  I believe there is more straight-forward way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I moved my Writer logic to a Runnable class (Thread class) Called MyWriterRunnable and in the MyWriter class I'm manually splitting the items List into 10 batches and calling MyWriterRunnable for each batch.

Comment: i would use the callable interface instead of Runnable. since you want to keep the throwns Exception from write() method.  If you use > java 6 of course!

Comment: The way you are doing is going to cause trouble.  May it works for this specific case but it shouldn't be considered as the way to go.  The biggest problem is the writer logic is not under same transaction as of the corresponding reader/processor logics.  It is going to cause problem.  Please adopt Spring Batch built-in solution by using TaskExecutor.

Comment: @AdrianShum TaskExecutor is for a chunk so reader and writer will both run under Taskexecutor threads right ? What I want is the ability to Write the 100 read records by 1 reader in parallel to each other and since I'm running the new threads under 1 writer they will be under 1 transaction right ?

Comment: You can make use of things like thread pool taskExecutor.  In such case, assume you have a 100-thread thread pool, what will happen is, (not very accurate but thinks like that simplify the thing a bit) you will have 100 threads, each having their own txn, and each of them will call reader and writer independently.  As long as the reader is thread-safe, you can have your 100 records handled by 100 threads in parallel

Comment: @AdrianShum i don't think you understood my question bud :) I don't want multiple threads of reader, if I did then I would be reading the same record multiple times. I want 1 reader thread and have the read records distributed to multiple threads of the Writer evenly.

Comment: @CMR I don't think you understood my answer in fact :)  What I was telling is not going to cause you same record read multiple times (if your reader is implemented right).  And, there is always one reader (not "multiple threads of reader"), only multiple threads performing the "chunk loop".  I strongly recommend you to look into the multi-thread step document and make sure you understand what's happening there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to process data in parallel, you would need to partition your data and assign the chunk to the linked step.  Your partition can be as simple as determining what to read per thread or it could take already read data from previous step and break them up into evenly distributed chunks and assign each reader of each thread a chunk to process.

Comment: could you please guide on how to achieve this. Thanks!